# Getting Started With Testing in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I'm a beginner in testing in Python. I'm working on Linux. I'm trying to do this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-testing/ . I run this code:

```
import unittest
class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum([1, 2, 3]), 6, "Should be 6")

    def test_sum_tuple(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum((1, 2, 2)), 6, "Should be 6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and get this error:

```
usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c] [-b]
                       [tests [tests ...]]
pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --port=41353
```

and I have no idea what to do about it. Please help!

Comment: How do you run the code? Please post the command line.

Comment: I run this in PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. It looks like an issue with how PyCharm calls the script.
Try adding a configuration:

1. To the top right, click `Edit Configurations`
2. In the window click `+`
3. Choose `Python` in the template list to the left.
4. To the right set `Script path` to the path of your script. (Assuming the file is called `test.py` that would be `/path/to/project/test.py`
5. Save the configuration (you might have to choose an interpreter from the dropdown before)
6. Run the script by using the green Play-Icon in the top right.

This worked really well for me and the outcome was what was described in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Thanks. I've been marking this whole code before and click 'shift' + 'alt' + 'e'. But when I run the script by using the green Play-Icon in the top right, it worked. So every test in pycharm should be running this way?

Comment: I generally create configurations for all projects and only use the play icon to run them. Or I just use the command line like `python test.py` if I am working just in an editor. You can also open a terminal in pycharm and execute it from there. Depends on your preferences